# optimize sql output

Tags: sql, sqlite, output

How to extract only the column names for tables in a database?

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('example3.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\'') #list all  tables therein
print c.fetchall() 
c.execute('SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=\'table\' AND name=\'students\'') #list columns in table 'students'
print c.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sqlite_master` to get the list of table names.  Then use [`PRAGMA table_info`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_table_info) to get the columns within the table.

Example:

```
PRAGMA table_info(students);
```

You'll need to repeat this for each table you want the column listing of.